# What are some good resources for aspiring web designers?

Tags: css, user-interface, user-experience

What are some good resources for aspiring web designers? I've been a software developer and web app builder for nearly a decade but my UI skills are from an engineer's perspective. I appreciate quality design and great UX and I'd like to become a better designer myself, what are some good resources to get started with and/or follow (i.e. blogs, twitter accounts, etc)?

I'll start with a couple that I think are relevant:

- http://www.alistapart.com/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/books/design2/ (the principles of beautiful web design)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wiki anyone? This is subjective.

Comment: I agree, this is subjective. What wiki are you referring to?

Comment: Mods can turn questions into a community wiki.

Comment: But we won't. This type of questions are no longer suitable here on Stack Overflow, and that's why CW was removed, it was used as an excuse for questions that were on the edge of or completely outside the rules. The single answer that was posted illustrates this perfectly, links which the poster *thinks* are relevant. There's no shortage of things that *seem* relevant to a subjective and argumentative question like this, and that's why they're no longer suitable. Questions have answers, opinions on things that may or may not be relevant aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few I think are relevant...

- http://www.awwwards.com
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com
- http://css-tricks.com